# How can I redirect to the homepage using JSOUP having POST request?

Tags: java, html, post, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to `login` into a website using `JSOUP` and the `login` is done using `post` request.

For `login` , I wrote the code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mysite.com/home")
  .data("username", "myusername")
  .data("pass", "mypassword")
  .userAgent("Mozilla")
  .post();
```

I am able to redirect to the homepage of the website , which I confirmed by printing the HTML by the below code.

```
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Now the website has made enhanced security features , after user `login` then instead of redirecting it to the homepage,
they are redirecting to the page which ask for the answer of the security question.

And after filling the answer in the `textbox` and clicking on the `submit` button , it redirects the user to the homepage.

Now when I am trying the same thing through `JSOUP`, the same above code redirects me to the security question page.

How I can fill the answer of the security question and get redirected to the homepage?

How I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its depend of logic on security question page. Of its use simple form POST or even GET, you can simulate the answer request with Jsoup too

Comment: @vaccum - I tried but still its not working.

Comment: firs of all - post your example of request, that cames after you filling the answer

Comment: open page where you filling the security answer and watch what request goes to the sever when you press "submit" button. With FireBug for example, or with Chrome built-in tool(F12)

Answer (score 0):

Download Firebug as others have suggested and open (and Enable) the NET panel. Submit the security question form on the website you're accessing, and watch for a `POST` request in Firebug. You can replicate this request as you've done above, and Jsoup should return the resulting response.

I've never used the .post() method of Jsoup, but I've always had success when connecting this way:

```
Document resultPage;

try {
    resultPage = Jsoup.connect("http://urlHere/")
    .userAgent("Whatever")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute()
    .parse();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Whatever
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden iframe to load the security question page and fill the answers using js in the page, It ll be little complicated, as you have to get security answer also from user first, before trying to login. It is possible to do, but i ll say its a **bad design**,